# How to pass string value rather pass event in multiselect material UI?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Hi I am using Material UI multi select in react typescript.

I am passing an event to child component to change the multi select value.

Parent component code is -

```
import {myData} from '../constant';
export const Parent = () => {
    const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
    
    const handleChangeMultiple = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
    const { options } = event.target as HTMLSelectElement;
    const value: string[] = [];
    for (let i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i += 1) {
        if (options[i].selected) {
        value.push(options[i].value);
        }
    }
    setPersonName(value);
    };
    
    return (
        <div>
            <Child
                onChange={handleChangeMultiple}
                myData={myData}
            />
        </div>
    );
    
}
```

Child Component code is -

```
import React from 'react'
export interface ChildProps {
    onChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => void;
    myData?: Array<Test<string, string>> | null;
}

export const Child = ({onChange , myData}: ChildProps) => {
    
    
    return (
        <div>
            <MultiSelect
                multiple
                native
                value={myData.val}
                onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>): void =>
                    onChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>)
                }>
                {myData &&
                    myData.multiSelectData &&
                    myData.multiSelectData.map(
                        (item: Test<string, string>) => (
                            <option key={item.key} value={item.value}>
                                {item.key.replace('_',' ')}
                            </option>
                        )
                    )}
            </MultiSelect>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I am passing the Change Event to get multi select value onChange in parent component. I don't want to pass any event I want to pass only string value & want to get this string value onchange multi select.

like in child component interface it should be - `onChange: (value:string) => void;`
and in child component it should be -

```
<MultiSelect
    multiple
    native
    value={myData.val}
    onChange={(event: React.FormEvent<EventTarget>): void =>
        onChange(someValue)
    }>
    {myData &&
        myData.multiSelectData &&
        myData.multiSelectData.map(
            (item: Test<string, string>) => (
                <option key={item.key} value={item.value}>
                    {item.key.replace('_',' ')}
                </option>
            )
        )}
</MultiSelect>
```

SO is there any way to pass string value to the event rather passing whole html event but yes multi select should work properly.

Comment: Do you mean an array of strings instead of a single string? Because a multiple select allows you to select more than one option.

Comment: @rateLess Yes We are passing whole html event to interface. I don't want to pass whole event to interface. I just want to pass some values to it. Either array of string or single string.

Comment: I probably misunderstood a few things, so let me see if I got this right. You want Parent's `handleChangeMultiple` to accept an array of strings. And you want Child's MultiSelect's `onChange` prop to call Parnet's `handleChangeMultiple` with an array of strings. Correct?

Comment: @rateLess Yes Right.

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE

Parent.js

```
import {myData} from '../constant';
export const Parent = () => {
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
  
  return (
        <div>
            <Child
                onChange={setPersonName}
                myData={myData}
                selectedValues={personName}
            />
        </div>
    );
    
}
```

Child.js

```
import React from 'react'
export interface ChildProps {
    onChange: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string[]>>;
    myData?: Test<string, string>[] | null;
    selectedValues: string[];
}

export const Child = ({onChange, myData, selectedValues}: ChildProps) => {
 
  
  return (
    <div>
      <MultiSelect
        multiple
        native
        value={selectedValues}
        onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>): void => {
          const { selectedOptions } = event.target;
          // Get the `value`s of the `selectedOptions`
          let values: string[] = Array.from(selectedOptions).map(selectedOption => selectedOption.value);
          // Call props' `onChange` function with values
          onChange(values);
        }}
      >
        {myData?.multiSelectData?.map((item: Test<string, string>) => (
          <option key={item.key} value={item.value}>
            {item.key.replace('_',' ')}
          </option>
        ))}
      </MultiSelect>
    </div>
  );
    
}
```

Comment: we are still passing whole event as parameter on onChange event. As I told you earlier I don't want to pass whole event. Is there any way to pass anything else other than whole event on onChange. ?

Comment: No, `values` is an array of strings, and it's passed on to the `onChange` prop declared in parent. If you're talking about `MultiSelect`'s `onChange` prop, it **will** pass an event object. Nothing we can do to change it.

Comment: I got your point but how would I implement this in my component ? & how would I change my interface in child component ?

Comment: can you help me in this ?

Comment: in line `let selectedOptions = [...options].filter(option => option.selected);` it is saying , Type 'HTMLOptionsCollection' is not an array type.

Comment: Changed `MultiSelect`'s `onChange` prop in Child.js. `selectedOptions` should contain an HTMLOptionsCollection with the selected values. `[...selectedOptions]` should cast them in an array.

Comment: still getting the same error, selectedOptions is not an array type..

Comment: Try replacing `[...selectedOptions]` with `Array.from(selectedOptions)`. I think TypeScript got hung up on that.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But when I am writing unit test case for the same then it is throwing an error. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedOptions' of undefined`.